# OpenMP: Is a barrier inside conditional code valid?

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp

In the [OpenMP Specification](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMP-API-Specification-5-1.pdf), the following restriction is posed for a barrier construct: (see p. 259, lines 30-31):

> Each barrier region must be encountered by all threads in a team or by
> none at all, unless cancellation has been requested for the innermost
> enclosing parallel region.

Just for completeness, the definition of a **region** by OpenMP specification is as follows (cf. p.5, lines 9 ff.):

> **region**
>
> All code encountered during a specific instance of
> the execution of a given construct, structured block sequence or
> OpenMP library routine. A region includes any code in called routines
> as well as any implementation code. [...]

I came up with a very simple example and I am asking myself whether it is at all valid, because the barriers are placed inside if-conditions (and not every barrier is "seen" by each thread). Nevertheless, the number of barriers is identical for each thread and experiments with two compilers show that the code works as expected.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include "omp.h"

double zerotime;

double gettime(void) {
 struct timeval t;
 gettimeofday(&t, NULL);
 return t.tv_sec + t.tv_usec * 1e-6;
}

void print(const char *format, ...) {
  va_list args;
  va_start (args, format);
  #pragma omp critical
  {
    fprintf(stdout, "Time = %1.1lfs ", gettime() - zerotime);
    vfprintf (stdout, format, args);
  }
  va_end (args);
}

void barrier_test_1(void) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (omp_get_thread_num() % 2 == 0) {
      print("Path A: Thread %d waiting\n", omp_get_thread_num());
      #pragma omp barrier
    } else {
      print("Path B: Thread %d waiting\n", omp_get_thread_num());
      sleep(1);
      #pragma omp barrier
    }
  }
}

int main() {
zerotime = gettime();
#pragma omp parallel
{
  barrier_test_1();
}
return 0;
}
```

For four threads I get the following output:

```
Time = 0.0s Path B: Thread 1 waiting
Time = 0.0s Path B: Thread 3 waiting
Time = 0.0s Path A: Thread 0 waiting
Time = 0.0s Path A: Thread 2 waiting
Time = 1.0s Path B: Thread 1 waiting
Time = 1.0s Path B: Thread 3 waiting
Time = 1.0s Path A: Thread 2 waiting
Time = 1.0s Path A: Thread 0 waiting
Time = 2.0s Path B: Thread 1 waiting
Time = 2.0s Path B: Thread 3 waiting
Time = 2.0s Path A: Thread 0 waiting
Time = 2.0s Path A: Thread 2 waiting
...
```

which shows that all the threads nicely wait for the slow **Path B** operation and pair up even though they are not placed in the same branch.
However, I am still confused from the specification, whether my code is at all valid.
Contrast this e.g. with [CUDA](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html) where the following statement is given regarding the related `__syncthreads()` routine:

> __syncthreads() is allowed in conditional code but only if the conditional evaluates identically across the entire thread block,
> otherwise the code execution is likely to hang or produce unintended
> side effects.

Thus, in CUDA, such code as written above in terms of `__syncthreads()` would be invalid, because the condition `omp_get_thread_num() % 2 == 0` evaluates differently depending on the thread.

**Follow-up Question:**

While I am quite ok with the conclusion that the code above is not following the specification, a slight modification of the code could be as follows, where `barrier_test_1()` is replaced by `barrier_test_2()`:

```
void call_barrier(void) {
  #pragma omp barrier
}

void barrier_test_2(void) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (omp_get_thread_num() % 2 == 0) {
      print("Path A: Thread %d waiting\n", omp_get_thread_num());
      call_barrier();
    } else {
      print("Path B: Thread %d waiting\n", omp_get_thread_num());
      sleep(1);
      call_barrier();
    }
  }
}
```

We recognize, that we have only a single barrier placed inside the code and this one is visited by all threads in the team. While the above code would be still invalid in the CUDA case, I am still unsure about OpenMP. I think it boils down to the question what actually constitutes the **barrier region**, is it just the line in the code or is it all code which has been traversed between subsequent barriers? This is also the reason, why I looked up the definition of a **region** in the specification. More precisely, as far as I can see there is no `code encountered during a specific instance of the execution of <the barrier construct>`, which is due to the statement about stand-alone directives in the spec (p.45, lines 3+5)

> Stand-alone directives are executable directives that have no
> associated user code.

and

> Stand-alone directives do not have any associated executable user
> code.

and since (p.258 line 9)

> The barrier construct is a stand-alone directive.

Maybe the following part of the spec is also of interest (p.259, lines 32-33):

> The sequence of worksharing regions and barrier regions encountered
> must be the same for every thread in a team.

**Preliminary Conclusion:**

We can wrap a barrier into a single function as above and replace all barriers by a call to the wrapper function which causes:

1. All threads either continue executing user code or wait at the   barrier
2. If we call the wrapper only by a subset of threads, this will cause a deadlock but will not lead to undefined behavior
3. Between calls to the wrapper, the number of met barriers is identical among the threads
4. Essentially this means, we can safely synchronize and cut through different execution paths by the use of such wrapper

**Am I correct?**

Comment: I guess it is invalid and works by pure accident. Spec requires **each** barier to be visited by all threads

Comment: Assuming this is supported: how the runtime could even know when a thread could reach the barrier and has to be waited? Indeed, the static analysis of a C++ program is in general undecidable (eg. halting problem). The number of thread is dynamic and threads are not executing (mostly) in lockstep like in CUDA (see the SMT model).

Comment: @JérômeRichard I am not asking how things could be done in principle, the question is whether the specification is allowing me to write such code and whether its behavior is well defined. Of course, thinking about how one might implement such a feature is an interesting but totally different question.

Comment: @tstanisl Please have a look at the follow-up question which addresses this subtle problem separately.

Answer (score 2):

> In the OpenMP Specification, the following restriction is posed for a
> barrier construct: (see p. 259, lines 30-31):
>
> > Each barrier region must be encountered by all threads in a team or by
> > none at all, unless cancellation has been requested for the innermost
> > enclosing parallel region.

That description is a bit problematic because `barrier` is a *stand-alone* directive.  That means it has no associated code other than the directive itself, and therefore there is no such thing as a "barrier region".

Nevertheless, I think the intent is clear, both from the wording itself and from the conventional behavior of barrier implementations: absent any cancellation, if any thread in a team executing the innermost parallel region containing a given `barrier` construct reaches that barrier, then all threads in the team must reach that same `barrier` construct.  Different barrier constructs represent different barriers, each requiring all threads to arrive before any proceed past.

> However, I am still confused from the specification, whether my code is at all valid.

I see that the behavior of your test code suggests that the two barriers are being treated as a single one.  This is irrelevant to interpreting the specification, however, because your code indeed does not satisfy the requirement you asked about.  The spec does not require the program to fail in any particular way in this case, but it certainly does not require the behavior you observe, either.  You might well find that the program behaves differently with a different version of the compiler or a different OpenMP implementation.  The compiler is entitled to assume that your OpenMP code conforms to the OpenMP spec.

Of course, in the case of your particular example, the solution is to replace the two `barrier` constructs in the different conditional branches with a single one immediately following the `else` block.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also thought the same thing but still I have a slight feeling that the wording of the specification is not really helpful. I also like that you suggest the solution. Of course in the simple problem above the solution is somehow trivial. But in a more complex problem, is there another way to synchronize different threads without  using barriers (or the restriction that the synchronization happens at the same point in code)?

Comment: @questioner, if you have multiple execution paths through a parallel region, and you want a barrier that cuts across those execution paths, then I think the best you can do with OpenMP is to make the all the paths come together, put the barrier there, and then have them split back apart.  There are several ways you could do that.  In truth, however, such a need is pretty unusual.

Comment: Also, @questioner, if you have complex synchronization requirements then it may be that they are not well supported by OpenMP.  Limitations on your flexibility is one of the prices you pay for the uniformity and simplicity of the OpenMP programming interface.

Comment: Of course there are limitations, but sticking to OpenMP is also nice because if I went e.g. to MPI, it is generally easier to synchronize but sharing data becomes a pain.

Comment: So as a conclusion: The restriction posed on the barrier construct is same as in the case of CUDA? We are allowed to place the barrier inside an if statement as long as the condition evaluates identically for all threads. Likewise it is also ok, to place barriers inside for loops for synchronization as long as all loop iterations are identical among the thread team?

Comment: Yes, @questioner, that sounds right.